# Iterate through array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to iterate through `ArrayPlayers` to find the oldest player. The logic would be to have a final pointer `Player *Oldest` to the oldest player. Here is my code:

```cs
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Player {
    int Age;
    char *Name;
public:
    Player() {}

    void setName(char *n) {
        Name = n;
    }

    void setAge(int a) {
        Age = a;
    }

    bool operator > (Player &P) {
        return Age > P.Age;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int NumPlayers;

    cout << "How many persons do you want to enter?\n";
    cin >> NumPlayers;

    Player *ArrayPlayers = new Player[NumPlayers];

    int age;
    char *name = new char;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumPlayers; i++) {
        cout << "Enter player name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter player age: ";
        cin >> age;
        ArrayPlayers[i].setName(name);
        ArrayPlayers[i].setAge(age);
    }

    //Find oldest player
    Player *Current = ArrayPlayers[0];
    Player *Previous = NULL;
    Player *Oldest = NULL;
    while (Current) {
        if (!Previous) {
            Oldest = Current;
            Current = Current + 1;
        } else {
            //Make comparison using overloading operator >
            if (Current > Oldest) { 
                Oldest = Current;
                Current = Current + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What happens is that the following instruction is not permitted:

```
Player *Current = ArrayPlayers[0];

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Player' to 'Player *'
```

Basically here I wanted to set a pointer to the first element of the array.

Can you point the reason for this error please? Do you see any other issues?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Avoid dynamic allocation (`new`). Read up on "const correctness", as your comparison operator wants write-access to the involved operands. Check out `std::string`.

Comment: Alternatively, make a `std::vector<Player>` then you can use `std::max_element`

Comment: Unrelated, but whenever you think "dynamic array" you should next think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Unrelated, but using a plain `char*` for the string means that you have to manage the memory it is pointing to (which the code does not). Consider using `std::string` instead, which does that management for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. In this case I can't use `std::string` or `std::vector` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Player *Current = ArrayPlayers[0];
```

with

```
Player *Current = &ArrayPlayers[0];
```

If it was not a typo (which I don't believe since the error message was pretty informative)
consider reading [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. So basically the pointer should always hold a memory address.

Comment: Actually just found out that `Oldest` will be empty after the while loop. Is there any other flaws in the code?

Comment: @Sam32 define "empty"

Comment: Tried to debug and it's showing {Age=??? Name=???}. I needed to display the name of the player on the screen after the while loop.

Comment: @Sam32 In that case `Oldest` is probably null. Also `Current > Oldest` does not do what you think it does. Read the tutorial.